# System.OutOfMemoryException' in PresentationCore.dll (Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program) WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

In WPF sample on building the sample with X86 configuration Manager, and in the runtime the out of memory exception occurs.kindly refer the below stack trace.

```
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CreateCachedBitmap(BitmapFrame frame, BitmapSourceSafeMILHandle wicSource, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, BitmapPalette palette)
```

On building the sample with X64 or ANYCPU the out of memory exception does not occurs.

Note:This out of memory in X86 configuration manager occurs in run time only when the size of text,apps is set to 100%.kindly refer the image.
[image]

Can anyone pls suggest a solution for resolving the issue?

Comment: What does the debugger say?  Maybe the call(s) to `CreateCachedBitmap` has invalid arguments, like unexpectedly large numbers, that will cause it the method call to fail since it tries to allocate something "too large".  In this case "too large" for your X86 build means anything close to 2GB.  So take a real close look at the requested bitmap parameters (especially `BitmapFrame`) and see what bitmap sizes it thinks it's trying to allocate for.

Comment: Hi @chris thank you for your update.But on using 150% as the size of the text and apps the out of memory exception does not occurs.

Comment: Don't let that distract you, your real task is to find out why it throws the exception for the 100% text size case.  At a guess, something in the XAML is behaving differently such that the call to `CreateCachedBitmap` gets sane values.  That's XAML for you.

Comment: I am find the rootcauuse of this issue ,the outofmeemory excepion occurs in the   BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad); this line ,on decoding the stream